# jquery ajax is not working in default.ctp file of cakephp 3.x layout

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.0

I want to call a function of cakephp controller using jquery ajax from my layout file default.ctp and want to set return response in notification section of every page but its not working.

This is my controller method:

```
public function cartItemCount(){    
    $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) as total_count FROM carts")->fetchAll('assoc');
    $this->response->body($result[0]['total_count']);
    return $this->response;
}
```

This is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $.get('<?php echo SITEURL;?>/NewOrders/cartItemCount',function(res){
            console.log(res);
            $(".cart_item").text(res);  
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I write this script in each and every view its working correct but I want write this script in default view so its work for all view without writing code in every view file. Please someone help me out.

Comment: When you put this code into your default.ctp layout, what goes wrong? There should be no difference between having the script in a view vs a layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store total count in session and then retrieve that session where you want to call.

Comment: it's too late..but  that is the alternate answer! thanks